# Why can't I set a breakpoint in a ASP.NET view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, debugging, asp.net-mvc-2

If I set a breakpoint in the compiled code (for instance in an action), I can then step through, and eventually am stepping through the generation of the View.

I've found this useful a couple of times, but it's tedious as you have to step through a lot of code to get there.

However, I can't set a breakpoint in view.  I just receive the message `'This is not a valid location for a breakpoint'` from VS2008. Why is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click on the code you want to break on and go to "Breakpoint -> Insert Breakpoint".

Why?  Must have something to do with the face your not working with a pure code file and hitting the left sidebar doesn't know which block of code to use.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Visual Studio 2010, but adding a debugger; statement does work.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing that comes to my mind is to use the debugger; keyword in the view, though I am not 100% sure it will work as in ASP.NET ajax site.

Comment: Works for me in Visual Studio 2010. In fact, it's the only approach that works.

Answer (score 2):

Click to the code where you want to debug and than press F9.

Comment: anthony - unfortunately, that won't work for the edge case that the OP mentions. however, nice reminder of the much forgotten short-cut keys. productivity to the fore, rather than convoluted menu traversals for such a basic need. nice one...

Answer (score 1):

UpTheCreek,

Not really a 'nice' way to do it, however, you can insert some 'flip-flop' code in your view that CAN have a breakpoint placed in it and then step from there. This code doesn't neccessarily have to perfom a function (tho obviously, would be useful if it did).

anyway, you don't want the crumbs, so here's the (meal) deal:

```
<%
    int rspId = 0;
    string uniqPageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "");  
%>
```

then, simply place the breakpoint at the side of any of those variable definitions.

Not clean and definately a 'jfar' markdown candidate :-)