# How to set a breakpoint in a ASP.NET MVC 2 view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, debugging, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to put a breakpoint in the code of a View in a ASP.NET MVC 2 project but Visual Studio complains that:

> "This is not a valid location for a breakpoint"

I have tried multiple ways to it (the "mouse way, F9, using the menu option). I am using Win2008 and running the site in IIS7.

Slandau's answer shows how to turn on compilation - a great start. Now, if only debugging would work!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I set a breakpoint in a view? (ASP.NET MVC 2 / VS2008)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603246/why-cant-i-set-a-breakpoint-in-a-view-asp-net-mvc-2-vs2008)

Comment: not a duplicate - this one is vs 2010. also, none of the accepted / graded answers from that question works

Comment: Right click, breakpoint, add breakpoint. This 100% works in VS2010, on MVC2 and MVC3. Enabling compiled views is not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the Razor view engine, you can be easy to set the break point and it works.